# Two controllers for main-app and sub-app with same url with angular ui-route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have two contollers 'BaseController' and 'SubController' defined for main-app and sub-app. The config for the two controllers point to empty url.

The following is the config for main-app:-

```
angular.module("main-app").config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('base', {
      url: "",
      views: {
        "base": {
          controller: 'BaseController' 
        }
      }
    });
}]);
```

This is the config for sub-app:-

```
 angular.module("sub-app").config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
  $stateProvider
  .state('sub', {
      url: "",
      views: {
        "patients": {
          templateUrl:"templates/scope/patients/patients_search.html",
          controller: 'PatientsController' 
        }
      },
    });
}]);
```

main-app includes sub-app.

How can I allow to load the both the controllers with the same empty url ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly two controllers for the same root view doesn't make any sense. This is because a controller needs a view context to act upon, i.e. a place in the `$scope` hierarchy.

I think what you instead need is to abstract your controllers into services, which are injectable into any controller. For example, create `mainsrv` and `subsrv` services, and then use a single root controller on `url: ''`. Then your root controller definition could look something like this:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', ['mainsrv', 'subsrv', function(mainsrv, subsrv){
        // use mainsrv and subsrv services here
    }]);
```

---

If you truly do want multiple controllers to load on the root view, create a single root view as above, but use `ng-controller` inside the views to specify the context of each controller. For example:

```
<div ng-controller="BaseController"></div>
<div ng-controller="PatientsController"></div>
```